# A confusion about c++ inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

when using inheritance, I read from a tutorial that says

> Conversely, if the most restricting access level is specified (private), all the base class members are inherited as private and thus cannot be accessed from the derived class.

So I test following code but the derived class can still access the member of base class.

Why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Polygon {
  protected:
    int width, height;
  public:
    Polygon():width(10),height(10){}
 };
class Rectangle: private Polygon {
  public:
    int area ()
      { return height; }
 };
int main () {
  Rectangle rect;
  cout << rect.area() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

output is 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derived type can access `public` and `protected` members of the base class. This is independent of the type of inheritance. But the members are all `private` in the derived type if the inheritance is `private`.

```
class Foo
{
 public:
  int i;
};

class Bar : private Foo
{
 public:
  void hello() { 
   ++i; // OK, I can see Foo's public and protected members 
  }
};

int main()
{
  Bar b;
  b.hello(); // accesses i internally. OK
  b.i;       // Error, i is private in Bar
}
```

Comment: I see. So the tutorial is kind of misleading me.

Comment: @Jianchen Yes, the paragraph you quoted is not very clear, it is very open to misinterpretation.

Comment: so I modify its example to see what happen. anyway thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Private inheritance means that all the base members become private *to the derived class*. The derived class itself can still access the members, but no further derived classes can.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ Standard

> If a class is declared to be a base class for another class using the
>   private access specifier, the public and protected members of the 
>   base class are accessible as private members of the derived class117.

So in your example protected data members of the base class

```
protected:
    int width, height;
```

are accessible as private members of the derived class and any member function of the derived class can access its private dara members.